# Methods on how to calibrate under/over-estimated probabilities

Tags: probability, estimation, forecasting, model-evaluation, calibration

I have Dataset with some purchase probabilities on different products of different users. 
 
After some comparison with observed purchase data for example by using conditional probability plots or evaluate the probabilities by calculating MAE, MSE or Hit Rates, I have found out which products are in general under- or overestimated.

**But** -> and here is my problem: 
 **How can I calibrate these probabilities more exaclty?**
 Is there any method from scientific area on this kind of topic?